# How can I Saute Liver & Onions and keep the liver moist?

Tags: liver

What I'm looking for specifically is a way to keep the liver from getting chewy or rock hard (yes those have been the outcomes of the the first two attempts). I'm not doing much with the liver (except salt) before cooking and only using olive oil in a copper pan - Any ideas?

Comment: Salt after frying only.

Answer (score 11):

Liver is very sensitive to over cooking, Fry the onions first and then throw in the liver for just long enough to cook it through

Answer (score 5):

I usually let the livers soak overnight in milk. Then i pat dry and fry with onions. even if i cook them for longer they will still stay moist. 
You can flavour the milk if you want. I usually put thyme and garlic.

Answer (score 0):

I flour and pan frie my liver first about 2mns on each side on med to high heat then remove, fro pan.  add onions along with some of my flour sautee until light brown add water, stir then re-add liver cook on low for 10mns. Moist and delicious.

Answer (score -1):

After cooking liver & onion in bacon grease, add 1/4 cup water, cover and steam liver for about 5 minutes. this adds moisture back to the liver. of course, don't overcook liver to begin with, but this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I only use calf liver and it's sliced thin. I soak it in milk (overnight, usually).I put a light coating of corn starch (flour) each side.I fry it in butter with a dab of coconut oil(it helps keep the butter from burning). It's only a couple of minutes med-hi heat to get each side fully browned on the bottom. When i flip it, i put all the onions on top of it and cover it 2-3 minutes. I take it off pink as it'll keep cooking and pale pink inside is fine to eat. Never tough.